# Dynamic google visualization in typescript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, google-visualization

I want to make it dynamic. Please anyone can help me to do this . Actually i am new in to angular & Typescript.

Code Snippet Here:
 Manually I am adding  row column. How to make it dynamic. Is it possible to iterate in loop.

We are using google charts.

```
const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Encounter Type', 'No of Encounters'],
[this.dataList[0][0], this.dataList[0][1]],
[this.dataList[3][0], this.dataList[3][1]],
[this.dataList[1][0], this.dataList[1][1]],
[this.dataList[2][0], this.dataList[2][1]],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply want to add the rows from `dataList`,
use a `forEach` statement

first, create an array with the column headings...

```
let arrayData = [
  ['Encounter Type', 'No of Encounters']
];
```

use `forEach` to load the rows...

```
this.dataList.forEach(function (row) {
  arrayData.push([row[0], row[1]]);
});
```

then create the data table from the array...

```
const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
```